# Configuring the autofac container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

How to configure a DI Container in a difficult situation?

There are 3 entities

```
class First: IFirst
public First (ISecond second)
{}
class Second : ISecond
public Second (IThird third, IOther other)
{}
```

Need to create the First. But at the same time:

1. IThird must be created by Autofac according to the rules configuration.
2. IOther must be given by me

I thought it would work:

```
auto.RegisterType<First>()
.WithParameter("second", new Second (auto.Resolve<IThird>(), new MyOther(myValue)))
```

But there is no method ContainerBuilder Resolve !

How this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't resolve service using a `ContainerBuilder` but you can use another overload with a delegate parameter that will give you access to the container.

```
cb.RegisterType<First>()
  .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "second", 
                 (pi, c) => new Second(c.Resolve<IThird>(), new MyOther(myValue)));
```

or

```
cb.RegisterType<First>()
  .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "second", 
                 (pi, c) => c.Resolve<ISecond>(TypedParameter.From<MyOther>(myValue)));
```